# node js on data only execute after writing to stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, telnet

hi i'm trying to connect to a telnet server using nodes net lib.

```
net = require('net')

con = new net.Socket()
con.connect(23,'10.0.0.120',()=>{
    console.log('telnet is connected')
})

con.on('data',(data)=>{
    console.log('telnet :' + data)
    con.destroy()
})

con.on('close',()=>{
    console.log('connection close')
})
```

the moment a socket is open i should receive a "login: " massage form the server, and then write the user name.

using wireshark i can see the data had been sent, but node is not reacting to the data
the weird part is when im sending some thing over the socket suddenly the react to the data from before

```
con.write('')
true
telnet :
login:
```

Comment: why con.destroy after receiving what might be only as little as just the first byte of data?

Comment: this was just for testing, evan 1 byte of data supposed to appear on the console yet it happense only after 'con.write()' no metter how much data already had arrived .....

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a listener for an event named `on` but, of course, you should be using the event named `data`.

Change...

```
con.on('on',(data)=>{
```

...to...

```
con.on('data',(data)=>{
```

Comment: sorry this was fixed in the code but i forgot to update the post as well, i am running it with on data
the data does arrive to the console but not in the time the data arrives, only after i write to 'con'